# Error : Call requires API level 23(current min is 15):

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, playback

I am trying to access the methods of the PlaybackParams class in my code but it gives me this error:

> Call requires API level 23 (current min is
>   15): android.media.PlaybackParams#PlaybackParams

The song is playing (not smoothly it kind buffers like in youtube videos) but the set speed isn't increasing the tempo of the song.
Also, the `seekTo()` methods works properly but the `setSpeed()` method doesn't.
I've been trying to figure out the bug in the code but haven't found my way through yet.

Also, if I delete the whole implementation and the access of PlaybackParams' methods then only the song plays otherwise (as with the provided code) it throws many (-38,0) errors and this error also:
`Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0xad7a2460, mCurrentState=0`

I know `state =0` error means it's trying to start the song before it's loaded but I don't know how to make everything fit in place properly.

Here's my code:

```
MediaPlayer mySong;
PlaybackParams params = new PlaybackParams();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mySong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fixyou);
}
public void musicPlayer (View view) {

        mySong.seekTo(20000);
        params.setSpeed(0.75f);
        mySong.setPlaybackParams(params);
        mySong.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the program on an emulator or a real device with API 23 because PlaybackParams class was newly added for API 23 and doesn't exist for lower API's.